# Is it possible to always take 3 objects and if only 2 exists it returns 3 but one has null values in?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return the 3 latest elements in a collection... If use Linq e.g. `.OrderByDescending(a => a.Year).Take(3)` then this is fine as long as the collection contains at least 3 elements. What I want is for it always to return 3, so for example if there are only 2 items then the last item would be a blank/initialised element (ideally where I could configure what was returned)

Is this possible?

Comment: `Take(3)` works just fine with with 2, 1 or even no matching element. What you ask for isn't `Take`. You ask to *generate* some unspecified elements if there are fewer items. Should those items be `null`? Non-null with properties set to their default values? For reference types (classes), the `default` is `null`. For value types (structs) the default is a struct with fields set to default values. If those fields hold reference types, they'll be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the sequence with another (lazily created) sequence of 3 elements:

```cs
var result = query
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => new ResultElement()))
    .Take(3);
```

Or perhaps:

```cs
var result = query
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new ResultElement(), 3))
    .Take(3);
```

(The latter will end up with duplicate references and will *always* create an empty element, so I'd probably recommend the former... but it depends on the context. You might want to use `Enumerable.Repeat(null, 3)` and handle null elements instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAndCreate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int amount, Func<T> defaultElement)
{
   int counter = 0;
   foreach(T element in input.Take(amount))
   {
       yield return element;
       counter++;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < amount - counter; i++)
   {
      yield return defaultElement.Invoke();
   }
}
```

Usage is

```
var result = input.OrderByDescending(a => a.Year).TakeAndCreate(3, () => new ResultElement());
```

One advantage of this solution is that it will create new elements only if they are acutally needed, which might be good for performance if you have a lot of elements to be created or their creation is not trivial.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHexGd